# Why preceding sibling element flows on top when the first sibling has position absolute?

Tags: html, css

I have two sibling `sections`, and used `position:absolute` on first section but the second section appears on top. I used the `position:relative` on second section but it does not work.
[image]

Here CSS for first section:

```
#slideshow > figure {
    animation: imageAnimation 30s linear infinite 0s;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    color: transparent;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

And CSS for second section:

```
#education {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

I want the second section flows normally after the first section.

Comment: Try setting position relative on both.

Comment: That's what postition absolute does, yes. If you want the two sections to display normally with respect to one another, put both of them in a container and give the container position absolute.

Comment: Please edit your question - in the end you wrote: "I want the second section appears normally (static) after the second section." - that can't be correct...

Comment: still: "the second section after the second section" - which after which?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything with `position: absolute` is taken out of the flow of elements - no space is automatically reserved for it. (other than for `relative` and `static`)

ADDITION after clearing of question: To have the second section begin below the first one, give it a `margin-top` that's as high as the first (absolutely positioned) section. This will move it down below the first section. Since I don't know the rest of your CSS, I can't give you much more details.